# please help me to solve the following diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have been trying this diophantine equation

Find all integer solutions to $x^2-xy+y^2=13$

but was unable to crack it.I have solved a few diophantine equations only.So please give a approach to solve this type of many problems and some methods which are used in these equations.

I think that we should try to factorise the equations so that we can pair up the solutions and we can see 13 is a prime number so it is easy to count the solutions or we can create a $(x-y)^2$ to solve and then do the factorisation.

Please while answering try to share the idea one should get while doing these type of questions and the basic approach on should hit to solve.

If there is any trick to solve these equation then please share that also,so that I can use that in further questions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $x^2-xy+y^2=\frac34(x-y)^2+\frac14(x+y)^2$, so you want to solve $3(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2=52$ for integers $x,y$.  Start by bounding $\lvert x-y\rvert$ and $\lvert x+y\rvert$.

Comment: how would i solve this further

Comment: whether i have to break 52 in a perfect square and the othe one in multiple of 3 and a perfect square

Comment: Just check the finitely many cases, or if you want a more advanced solution, work with $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$.

Comment: and also share the way how you get to this format of the equation and how would one think of it to get there.

Comment: what is $Z(C_3)$

Comment: pls share how you get to that solution.and if i do another question then how may i get that type of equations as solutions

Answer (score 4):

If both $x,y$ are positive you can use the inequality $x^2 + y^2 \ge 2xy$. We have:

$$13 = x^2 + y^2 - xy \ge 2xy - xy = xy$$

Thus we have $xy \le 13$. Now WLOG let $x \ge y$. Then we have that $y \le \sqrt{13}$. Thus $y=1,2$ or $3$.

Plug these into the equation to check for solutions. Also don't forget that if $(x,y)$ is a solution, so is $(y,x)$.

Note that this will yield the negative solutions too, as $(x,y)$ is a solution if and only if $(-x,-y)$ is a solution, too.

If one of $x,y$ is positive and the other is negative you can WLOG assume that $x$ is positive and $y = -m$, where $m$ is non-negative integer. Then you want to solve $13 = x^2 + xm + m^2$. Similarly as above you get that:

$$3xm \le 13$$

And if we set $x \ge m$ we have that $m = 1$ or $2$. Again plug these values into the equation to check for solutions.

Comment: how you applied the AM-GM inequality in the expression,and i do not know anything about WLOG just the full form without loss of generality.so please help by explaining this further or by any other method

Comment: @Aryan24k I explaine how I used AM-GM. And yes, WLOG means exactly that. What I mean is that you can assume that $x \ge y$, as if $(x,y)$ is a solutions so is $(y,x)$

Comment: you have assumed that y is less then x .that's ok but how you get y is less then equal to root 13

Comment: @Aryan24k $13 \ge yx \ge y^2 \implies \sqrt{13} \ge y$

Comment: Ok thanks i get what you have done

Comment: Please can you tell me why you have got the thought of using am-gm inequality.what was the main aim of doing that and not using other methods

Answer (score 1):

I would write $$x_{1,2}=\frac{y}{2}\pm \sqrt{13-\frac{3}{4}y^2}$$
We consider here the equation $$x^2-xy+y^2-13=0$$ as an equation in $x$ using the quadratic formula. So we get $$|y|\le \sqrt{\frac{52}{3}}$$ this means $$|y|\le 4$$
It must be $$13\geq \frac{3}{4}y^2$$ since the radicand must be non negative.

Comment: please clarify how you get to this solution and how may i will solve that down further

Comment: How you get y is less than equal to root 53/3

Comment: I think the expression inside the square root can be negative also.so should we do D less than equal to 0 to make it always positive and then we can get a range bound in y and can assume the integers values of y.

Comment: The expression inside the square root must be greater or equal to zero.

Comment: Ok thanks i got what you have done

Comment: But i think it should be root 52/3 as 13*4 is 52

Comment: Thanks for your help..

Comment: Yes it is, $$4\cdot 13=52$$

Comment: Can you explain what is parametric solution in the below answer

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below,

$x^2-xy+y^2=13$ -----$(1)$

Equation $(1)$ has parametric solution:

$x=w(3k^2+2k-4)$

$y=w(4k^2-6k-1)$

Where,  $w=[(1)/(k^2-k+1)]$

For $k=2$, we get $(x,y)=(4,1)$

Comment: How you get the parametric solution and what is parametric solution

Comment: Please also share what approach you have taken when you first saw the question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Comment: As an example, instead of writing $y = f(x)$, you write $(x, f(x))$. Or with a third variable $t$: $(x(t), y(t))$.  If $x(t) = t$ and $y(t)=t^2$ it is same with $y = x^2$ etc.